# How to update the value of a context provider without all of the children re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-state

I have a stream of data that React accepts in the form of custom JS events. Each time the event fires, I need to update the value of a context provider so that the consuming components can re-render. However, I don't want all of the children to re-render, which is what's happening now because I am handling each new JS event with an update to the provider's state. I'm wondering how to avoid the children from re-rendering on this state change.

```
const DataListener = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const Data = createContext([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('newDataEvent', (e) => {
            setData([...data, e.detail]);
        })
    }, []);

    return (
        <Data.Provider >
            {props.children}
        </Data.Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030018/react-context-with-hooks-prevent-re-render does this answer your question ?

Comment: or you can look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317371/react-context-api-and-avoiding-re-renders

Comment: in my opinion, their is better things to do with your time rather than memoizing this..

Comment: [Just to be clear, rerender in this context means calling render for all components, it doesn’t mean React will unmount and remount them. It will only apply the differences following the rules stated in the previous sections.][1]

  [1]: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#tradeoffs

Reading this I think you might just work on a problem that is not actually a problem