# When using React Context prevent re-render of child components that don't need the new context value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

**Problem** : https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wing-zv45id?file=/src/App.js

**What I am doing** : I am trying to call an api from component `ContextChild1` and updating the api response data in my context component `BaseContextProvider`. All state variables in `BaseContextProvider` along with `setData` function are being passed as a context to all the child components - `ContextChild1` and `ContextChild2`

**What is happening** : `ContextChild1` is getting re-executed when `userData` is updated in `BaseContextProvider`. This is working fine as it should. I know the re-execution of `ContextChild1` is happening because the context is getting changed with the `userData` update in `BaseContextProvider` but this `userData` is NOT required by `ContextChild1` instead it is required by `ContextChild2`.

**What I want to achieve** : I want `ContextChild1` to NOT execute when `userData` state in `BaseContextProvider` is updated from `ContextChild1`.

In the demo link above, below are the series of logs you will see in console  :(Ignore the ***(2)*** printed at the start of each log line in the demo)

```
    (2)base context provider executed    
    (2)child1 executed
    (2)child2 executed
    (2)api called from child1
    (2)base context provider executed 
    (2)child1 executed(don't want this re-render) 
    (2)child2 executed
```

**Note** : you will see below log lines as well directly after the above logs, but this is something weird I am seeing in *codesandbox* however this is not seen in *stackblitz*. So please ignore these logs as it might mislead you.

```
(2)base context provider executed
(2)child1 executed
(2)child2 executed
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself. A code sandbox link is fine as a reference, in addition to the [mcve] in the question.

Comment: might help https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156

Comment: All of the techniques explained in the following answer apply to your situation: [React context with hooks prevent re render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030018/react-context-with-hooks-prevent-re-render)