# How to pass Mobx store as props to react compoent

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have this app that uses mobx, in it there is a component called "Listings" that uses some state from mobx to render a list of items.

The way it is right now, is that the `Listings` component gets the data it needs(`store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood]`) from inside of it by using the mobx store like so:

```
const Listings = () => {
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);

  return useObserver(() => (
    <div className="pa2">
        {store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood] &&
          store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood].map((rest, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i} className="pa2 listing">
                <p>{rest.name}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
    </div>
  ));
};
```

But i think this is wrong, as it couples the component with the data, I want instead to pass that data via props so it can be reusable.

What is the correct way to do this? Right now my `App` looks like this, where it's being wrapped around a `storeProvider`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <StoreProvider>
      <div className="mw8 center">
        <Header title="EasyLunch" subTitle="Find Pizza, Burgers or Sushi in Berlin the easy way"/> 
        <FixedMenu menuItem1={"Pizza"} menuItem2={"Burger"} menuItem3={"Sushi"} />
        <p className="b tc pt3">or...</p>
        <Search /> 
        <Listings />
      </div>
    </StoreProvider>
  );
}
```

My idea is to extract everrything inside the `StoreProvider` into another component that has a store and returns the jsx via `useObserver` so that I can acces the store and then pass what i need as props to the other components. like this:

```
const Wapper = () => {
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);
  return useObserver(() => (
    <div className="mw8 center">
      <Header title="EasyLunch" subTitle="Find Pizza, Burgers or Sushi in Berlin the easy way" />
      <FixedMenu menuItem1={"Pizza"} menuItem2={"Burger"} menuItem3={"Sushi"} />
      <p className="b tc pt3">or...</p>
      <Search />
      <Listings listings={store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood]} />
    </div>
  ))
}
```

And then on the listings component change the hard coded `store.restaurantResults[store.selectedFood]` inside to use the props that is being passes now, that is called listigs like so:

```
const Listings = ({listings}) => {
  const store = React.useContext(StoreContext);

  return useObserver(() => (
    store.loading
      ? <Loading />
      : <div className="pa2">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap">
          {listings &&
            listings.map((rest, i) => {
              return (
                <div key={i} className="pa2 listing">
                  <img className='object-fit' src={rest.image_url} alt="restuarant" />
                  <p>{rest.name}</p>
                  <p>{rest.location.address1}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
  ));
};
```

And this works, but is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: still depends directly on `store` for `loading`, can be passed as prop, too

Comment: but if im passing the whole store i could do store.loading.... but that still doesnt work bc store is always undefined

Comment: sorry, but it improves nothing ... instead one specialised `<RestaurantLister/>` you're creating more reusable (?) the same ... and increases Wrapping Hell ... doesn't make sense for mobx and context usage optimization (minimize rerenderings)

Comment: you can just pass `loading={store.loading}` and use `loading` inside

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50817822/6124657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `<Listings/>` can be provided with `listing` and `loading` you can:

```
const Listings = ({listings, loading}) => {
  if(loading) return <Loading />
  return (
    <div className="pa2">
      <div className="flex flex-wrap">
        {listings && listings.map((rest, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} className="pa2 listing">
              <img className='object-fit' src={rest.image_url} alt="restuarant" />
              <p>{rest.name}</p>
              <p>{rest.location.address1}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

No observables used, no `useObservable` required.

You want to `useObservables` on `store` for listings then no reason to wrap all components with `useObservable`. You should wrap `<Listings/>` only.

Comment: a ha! thats the thing.. i must pass them as individual props, already converted into values.. not the whole store..thx!

Comment: ... you can use graphql, `useQuery` etc. instead all readux/mobx ;)

Answer (score -1):

I usually define my store as a global, so every component has visibility of it:

```
class Store {
  @observable myVar
}

global.store = new Store()
```

And in my components i just use it:

```
@observer
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    store.myVar = 0
  }

  setMyVar (a) {
    store.myVar += 1
  }

  render () {
    return <button onClick={this.setMyVar}>
      Clicked {store.myVar} times
    </button>
  }
}
```

Comment: globals should be avoided in js for many reasons (search/google), using context is a react recommended solution for that